# How can I allow an API to remotely access my code without revealing it?

Tags: python, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

A friend is building an API. He wants my machine learning algorithm (written in Python) to be incorporated into this API. I have heard that his API can **'*remotely* access'** my algorithm and in this way I don't have to reveal what the code actually is.

If this is all true, can someone point me in the direction of building this. I know very little about API's!

Apologies, I'm a newbie to this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could upload your code to a server and create your own API for your friend's API to use.

An example of how to create a python server: http://www.acmesystems.it/python_httpserver

Basically, when you get a request, call your algorithm script and pass the data received from the request, then return an appropriate response.

For better security, you could require some identification in the request to prove that it really is your friend that's sending it. If you're afraid of your code getting leaked if the server would be hacked, you could use tools like docker.com to host the server script and your algorithm script in two different virtual machines.